# How to Enable SSL Secure for sitecore shell cookies

Tags: sitecore-client, cookies

I have added  below code snippet (as in Andy Burns Blog https://andrewwburns.com/2016/10/21/secure-your-sitecore-cookies/ ) to secure the Sitecore cookies.

```
<System.Web> and <httpCookies> set requireSSL:
```

`<httpCookies requireSSL="true" />`
And in `<forms>` set requireSSL too.
`<forms name=".ASPXAUTH" cookieless="UseCookies" requireSSL="true" />`

It is working for Sitecore cookies but when I’m login to the Sitecore then again recording Sitecore shell cookies(inject from the Sitecore javascript files) and they were not SSL secured.

[image]
I wanted to know Is there way to enable SSL secure for Sitecore shell cookies from custom config.

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore describes it as a bug in their tracking system (reference number 232082) and provided a possible workaround which is worked for me.

- Open the “\Website\sitecore\shell\Applications\Content Manager\Content Editor.js” file.
- Replace the following lines:

> `scForm.setCookie("scContentEditorFoldersWidth", pos);`
> `scForm.setCookie("scContentEditorFolders", visible ? "1" : "0");`

With these lines:

> `scForm.setCookie("scContentEditorFoldersWidth", pos, undefined, undefined, undefined, true);`

`scForm.setCookie("scContentEditorFolders", visible ? "1" : "0", undefined, undefined, undefined, true);`

- Clear the browser’s cache.