# Set Http and Secure flag for Sitecore Shell#Lang cookie

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-commerce, cookies

Is there a way in c# to set Http and Secure flag true for shell#lang cookie (in my case website#lang). As this cookie is Sitecore cookie.

[image]

Any help/pointer would be a great help.

Thanks

Comment: The cookie secured in that link is scContentEditorFolderWidth and not shell#lang and that too for ContentEditor 

However I want to secure shell#lang cookie (in my case its website#lang) which is coming in my website cookies

Please suggest

Comment: Hello,

Can anyone please help on this?

Comment: Hello,

Answer here https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/12890/how-to-enable-ssl-secure-for-sitecore-shell-cookies is not helpful.

As my issue is different from this, I am trying to secure shell#lang cookie specifically.

However, solution provided in above link is to secure:
ASP.NET_SessionId,
scContentEditorFoldersWidth,
SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE


Any pointer will be great help!

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Mark, I think this is not considered a duplicate since it has a different cookie object. Also, I can't find any js that has setCookie for "shell#lang".